# How do I write linked list in Solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development

In any language, I would write following:

```
struct Node {
   void* data;
   Node* next;
}

...

head.next = new Node(data, null)
```

But it seems that solidity doesn't have a concept of pointers.

How could it be done here?

**EDIT**
The answer at the end of [Are there well-solved and simple storage patterns for Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity) is not enough for me as I also need to insert nodes to the middle.

Comment: (Linked-lists are mentioned at the end of the accepted answer.)

Comment: I have seen this example, but it doesn't seem to fit to me, because I need to insert in the middle while this code appends only.

Comment: My blog has an implementation of a doubly linked list: https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/03/30/storage-patterns-doubly-linked-list/.

Comment: @smarx thank you for the link. It's seems to be a proper approach. Brb when done.

Comment: @smarx I tried your approach and I get `1>Dynamic exception type: class boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<struct dev::solidity::UnimplementedFeatureError>
1>std::exception::what: Copying of type struct Season.StatusUpdate memory[] memory to storage not yet supported`

Comment: You'd have to share your code.

Comment: @smarx https://gist.github.com/Pzixel/995969e188df1b6c0054957e947f6073

Comment: The error means what it says: you can't create that type in memory and then copy it into storage. I'd suggest opening a new question with a minimal repro so people can suggest alternatives.

Comment: @smarx I currently workarounded it with `nodes.length++` and then writing directly into new storage. It seems that it's a common way to do such a thing in Solidity. Thank you for your post, it was really priceless.

Comment: That's the alternative I would have suggested. I'm glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a library](https://github.com/o0ragman0o/LibCLL) on GitHub which does the trick for circular doubly linked lists. Although I haven't actually used the library, I referenced it heavily when writing my own similar implementation. Even if you don't use it, there's easily enough to work with to make a simple linked list.